# Divergence criterion by rearranging

Tags: sequences-and-series

The usual results on rearranging series give that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k $ converges unconditionally, i.e. the limit doesn't change if we rearrange the order of summation, if and only if $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_k| < \infty.$$
This immediately gives the following divergence test: If we can find two permutations $\sigma, \tau$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\sigma(k)} \neq \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{\tau(k)},$$
then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_k|$ must be divergent. I was wondering if this criterion is somehow useful. By this I mean: Are there any series whose divergence can be shown the easiest in this way?